# Como definir o timeout para dump no database.php?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Eu preciso aumentar o `timeout` do `MySQL` para a execução de um processamento de `dump` do banco.

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'dump_command_timeout' => 60 * 20, // 5 minute timeout
            'dump_using_single_transaction' => true,
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
         ],
```

Estou usando o `dump_command_timeout` do pacote [spatie/laravel-backup](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-backup), mas não funciona sendo que o servidor cai em ***60 segundos***. Pesquisei e não encontrei nada a respeito.

Alguém usa este pacote e sabe como devo configurar o `database.php`?

Comment: Essa base de dados sua é grande?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic sim, 1,1 GB e vai crescer....

Comment: Então, é isso @MarceloGomes, o Servidor tem um tempo hábil para execução de um `Script` e esse backup com esse plugin acredito que seja para bancos bem menores.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic conhece alguma ferramenta ou componente que possa me ajudar neste trabalho?

Comment: estou procurando algo e logo se achar coloco alguma resposta pra ti, mas, até agora nada! o banco é muito grande e ai foge um pouco do script porque depende do servidor, mas, vamos tentar

Comment: ok se consegui, farei o mesmo. obrigado